# Groups acting on infinite dimensional CAT(0) cube complex

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

I have seen many examples where a finitely generated infinite group acts properly/freely by isometry on finite dimensional CAT(0) cube complexes. Examples of such groups are discussed in many articles.

My question is

> What are the examples of infinite, finitely generated groups that acts properly (or freely) on infinite dimensional CAT(0) cube complex?

I also come across the statement in the paper by Roller and Niblo where finite dimension condition is not required (or I don't know if they need it somehow).

> **Theorem** A group acts fixed-point-freely on a CAT(0) cube complex if and only if it contains a codimension-one subgroup.

Do these groups act properly on infinite dimensional CAT(0) cube complex?

I thought my search is over after going through the [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308865/group-acting-on-a-cat0-cube-complex-then-acting-also-on-a-tree/308868) when I came across the example of Thompson groups T and V. However, these groups are not finitely generated.

Comment: Eh? $T$ and $V$ are in fact finitely generated (and finitely presented, and type $F_\infty$). I think they are a perfect example of the sort of thing you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks for both the answers! I didn't know that they are finitely generated.

Comment: Worth mentioning one little fact where the complex need not be finite dimensional: If a group acts properly on a CAT(0) cube complex then the group has the Haagerup property. This is the main thing I'm aware of that "still works" without finite dimensionality.

Comment: This is called "Property PW" in some papers. I studied/surveyed it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5982).

Answer (score 12):

Natural examples of finitely generated groups acting properly on median graphs of infinite cubical dimension (or, if you prefer, on infinite-dimensional CAT(0) cube complexes) include:

- Thompson's groups $F$, $T$, and $V$. There are also many other Thompson-like groups.
- Groups defined by infinite small cancellation presentations.
- Grigorchuk groups.
- Some lamplighter groups, e.g. lamplighters over free groups.
- Some tubular groups.
- Some diagram groups.

About groups containing codimension-one subgroups, there is no reason for your fixed-point free action to be proper. For instance, every finitely generated group with an infinite abelianisation contains a codimension-one subgroup but it may not act properly on a median graph. A stupid example could be a product $G \times \mathbb{Z}$ where $G$ has Property (T). Or a free product of groups with (T) acts non-trivially on a tree but does not act properly on a median graph.